# Date and Time incorrect on compute engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have restarted my Compute Engine VM instance after I suspended it a month ago. It starts up OK, however the date and time is for 13th January 2021 rather than the current date of 10th March 2021. I can see `ntpd` running, so I'm not sure why the date hasn't been synced up with current date.

Comment: "ntpd running" is not sufficient. You need to check its status, for example `ntpq -pn` lists all NTP peers, connectivity information, etc. It could be that ntpd doesn't change the time because it is too far off, in which case the answer could help.

Answer (score 1):

I did this and it updated the date:

```
sudo -i ntpdate -u 0.europe.pool.ntp.org
```